# How to obtain form's inner width and height

Tags: c#, forms, height, width

As per title.

I am writing a program that all components can adjust size automatically by form's size.

When I using `this.Width` and `this.Height` properties, its return value is the width and height of whole form (red frame).

How to get the form's width and height of its inner area (green frame)?

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `this.ClientSize.Width` and `this.ClientSize.Height`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9278sfx2(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can check by this.ClientSize.Width and this.ClientSize.Height. Or you can put Panel in form and Dock fill and get this.panel1.width/ this.panel1.height as well.